# Automatic Update not working: Why are CoreData FetchedResults not passed to included views

Tags: swiftui, ios13, xcode11

In my app I have data from CoreData. This data is updated by Bluetooth.
Data is retrieved with

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), animation: nil) var beacons: FetchedResults<Beacon>
```

and when the CoreData data is updated, `beacons` is updated, too, and the view is updated with this current values.

But when I use included views from a different file, they're not updated.

My code reads

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), animation: nil) var beacons: FetchedResults<Beacon>

    static func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Beacon> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Beacon> = Beacon.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]

        return request
    }

func debugPrint() -> AnyView {
    let temperature = beacons[0].adv!.temperature
    return AnyView ( Text("temp = \(temperature)") )
}

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
                    debugPrint()
                    ForEach(beacons.filter { $0.isActive }) { beacon in
                        NavigationLink(destination: BeaconDetail(beacon: beacon)) {
                            BeaconListEntry(beacon: beacon)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in a different file

```
struct BeaconListEntry : View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    var beacon: Beacon

    var body: some View {
        Text(verbatim: String(format:"%.1f °C", beacon.adv!.temperature))
    }
}
```

The `debugPrint()`line is updated as new data is available in CoreDate, but the `BeaconListEntry`view is not updated. If I manually switch Tabs, is is updated.

Why does this happen and how can I correct the code?